# MAX,MIN of a 3 variable function : Correctness in writing

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

I have to find max,min of $f(x,y,z)=1/(3x^2 +z^2)$constrained on a region $D$

$D =\{x^2+z^2-y^2-3\le 0\}$ -> $g(x,y,z)=x^2+z^2-y^2-3=0$

- I used the Lagrange multiplier method: and I got the points

$P_1(\pm\sqrt{3},0,0)$->$f(P_{1})=1/9$

$P_2(0,0,\pm\sqrt{3})$->$f(P_{2})=1/3$

- So My question is : (with the fact that $f(x,y,z)$ doesn't contain a $y$ )It is more correct to write the points with $y = 0$ or with $y=y$, like that:

$P_{1a}(\pm\sqrt{y^2+3},0,0)$->$f(P_{1a})=1/(3y^2+9)$

$P_{2a}(0,0,\pm\sqrt{y^2+3})$->$f(P_{2a})=1/(y^2+3)$

Comment: I haven´t checked the calculation, but $y=y$ is the right intuition.

Comment: The cost function is not defined for $x=z=0$? It is unbounded above nearby. Furthermore, by appropriate choice of $y$, you can make the cost be any value in $(0,\infty)$, so it has no $\min$ either. In particular, the $\inf$ is zero and the $\sup$ is $=\infty$. Lagrange is sort of irrelevant here.

Comment: If in both case you have obtained $y=0$ then we need to set $y=0$.

Comment: my question arises from the fact that the second equation of the Lagrange system is : $0+\lambda (-2y)=0$ that means that it is TRUE for $y=0$ or $\lambda =0$

Comment: ($x=0$ and $z=0$) is not defined for real numbers

Comment: @NPLS: Huh??? ${}{}$

Comment: for (0,y,0) !..

Comment: Just to reiterate, the function does **not** have a $\min,\max$ on $D$.

Comment: of course , but it does on the boundary of $D$

Comment: @copper.hat Why not? See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=min+1%2F(3x%5E2+%2Bz%5E2),+x%5E2%2Bz%5E2-y%5E2-3%5Cleq+0).

Comment: I don't like repeating myself.

Comment: @copper.hat But maybe your statement was wrong.

Comment: of course, you don't like repeating yourself, (if you repeat the same process you will have the same results) I'd suggest trying a new way to explain your concept is the correct way to go

Comment: You could read my comments and see if they are true rather than blindly trusting WA.

Comment: I didn't, @callculus did

Comment: @NPLS Yes,  I did.

Comment: Take $x_n=z_n=n, y_n = 2n$, then $(x_n,y_n,z_n) \in D$ and $f(x_n,y_n,z_n) \to 0$. Take $x_n=z_n = {1\over n}$, $y_n = 0$, then $(x_n,y_n,z_n) \in D$ and $f(x_n,y_n,z_n) \to \infty$. Is that convincing enough?